# AWS Cloudformation Link API Key to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, api-key

I have the following Cloudformation template I am trying to deploy via SAM. This template correctly creates the DynamoDB table, an API Key, a Lambda function and the API Gateway, but I cannot figure out what I need to specify in the template to associate the API KEY with the API Gateway.

I have found plenty of snippets showing partial examples, but I am struggling to piece it all together.

Thank you in advance,

Denny

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  TableName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'influencetabletest'
    Description: (Required) The name of the new DynamoDB table Minimum 3   characters
    MinLength: 3
    MaxLength: 50
    AllowedPattern: ^[A-Za-z-]+$
    ConstraintDescription: 'Required parameter. Must be characters only. No numbers allowed.'
  CorsOrigin:
    Type: String
    Default: '*'
    Description: (Optional) Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) Origin. You can specify a single origin, all "*" or leave empty and no CORS will be applied.
    MaxLength: 250
Conditions:
  IsCorsDefined: !Not [!Equals [!Ref CorsOrigin, '']]
Resources:
  ApiKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    DependsOn:
      - ApiGetter
    Properties:
      Name: "TestApiKey"
      Description: "CloudFormation API Key V1"
      Enabled: "true"
  ApiGetter:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prd
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        paths:
          /getdynamicprice:
            post:
              responses: {}
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaGetter.Arn}/invocations
  LambdaGetter:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./index.js
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref TableName
          IS_CORS: IsCorsDefined
          CORS_ORIGIN: !Ref CorsOrigin
          PRIMARY_KEY: !Sub ${TableName}Id
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref TableName
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /getdynamicprice
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGetter
  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: !Ref TableName
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: !Sub "${TableName}Id"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: !Sub "${TableName}Id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
Outputs:
  ApiKeyID:
    Value: !Ref ApiKey
  ApiUrl:
    Value: !Sub https://${ApiGetter}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/prod/getdynamicprice
    Description: The URL of the API Gateway you invoke to get your dynamic pricing result.
  DynamoDBTableArn:
    Value: !GetAtt DynamoDBTable.Arn
    Description: The ARN of your DynamoDB Table
  DynamoDBTableStreamArn:
    Value: !GetAtt DynamoDBTable.StreamArn
    Description: The ARN of your DynamoDB Table Stream
```

Comment: Hi @Denny , how do you enabled `APIkeyRequried` property in SAM ? Because after attaching `apikey` to a `apiplan` you need to enable this property for sending the header string in the request right ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit (04/22/2020): there now seems to do all this using AWS SAM. Please see answer below

Here's a sample template where I have connected my API to a API key. But that's only been possible because I am using `usage plans`. I believe that is the primary purpose of an API key. [API gateway usage plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)

```
ApiKey: 
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
  Properties: 
    Name: !Join ["", [{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-apikey"]]
    Description: "CloudFormation API Key V1"
    Enabled: true
    GenerateDistinctId: false
ApiUsagePlan:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan"
  Properties:
    ApiStages: 
    - ApiId: !Ref <API resource name>
      Stage: !Ref <stage resource name>     
    Description: !Join [" ", [{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "usage plan"]]
    Quota:
      Limit: 2000
      Period: MONTH
    Throttle:
      BurstLimit: 10
      RateLimit: 10
    UsagePlanName: !Join ["", [{"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-usage-plan"]]
ApiUsagePlanKey:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey"
  Properties:
    KeyId: !Ref <API key>
    KeyType: API_KEY
    UsagePlanId: !Ref ApiUsagePlan
```

There does not seem to be a way to do this without a usage plan.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I feel like I'm getting much closer. I'm now getting an error that API Stage not found under the UsagePlan.  I set the stage to prd, which is the stagename under ApiGetter.  Perhaps that is referring to something else?

Comment: I wanted to follow up and thank you. It turned out to be two things. I was providing an incorrect value to <API resource name> and I needed to add a DependsOn to ApiKey, ApiUsagePlan, and ApiUsagePlanKey to ensure they were created in the correct order.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: +Upvote.@ASR with your help i had created api key and attached to plan to particular stage. But i am struck at `ApikeyRequired` property. How can i enable that in SAM ? In cloudformation we have this property in `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` but i dont know where it is in SAM . I tried like this but no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936126/how-to-enable-apikeyrequired-property-in-sam

Comment: @Private This might be late. But i was unable to add API key using SAM. I think i cam across a post in AWS Github forum that it is not supported in SAM.

Comment: You can't disassociate the API key from the usage plan because API Keys are less about security and more about metering access. AWS does a good job discussing this in the section "Best Practices for API Keys and Usage Plans" found in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html.

Answer (score 8):

I did try the suggestion from ASR but ended up with a simpler approach.
The AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) contains prepackaged handling that doesn't necessitate the use of resources of the ApiGateway type.

To create an API Gateway with a stage that requires an authorization token in the header the following simplified code should do it for you :

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        ApiKeyRequired: true
        UsagePlan:
          CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
          UsagePlanName: GatewayAuthorization [any name you see fit]
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 30
      CodeUri: .
      Events:
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /content
            Method: POST
            RequestParameters:
              - method.request.header.Authorization:
                  Required: true
                  Caching: true
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayEndpoint [The logical name of your gateway endpoint above]
```

The elements:

```
Auth:
   ApiKeyRequired: true
   UsagePlan:
     CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
```

is what does the trick.
Cloudformation handles the plumbing for you, ie. the Api Key, UsagePlan and UsagePlanKey is automatically created and binded.

Although the docs are definitely not best in class they do provide some additional information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-resources-and-properties.html

Comment: when you say automatically, you mean that just that declaration you highlighted is enough & `SAM` does the rest? or do you first create key, usage plan etc with CFN & then attach?

Comment: @ASR yes, the declaration highlighted is enough and everything else is done by SAM

Comment: My dude, you saved me, if i could i would give you 100 rep

Comment: Thank you limboy. That was of much great help. My requirement is to restrict API access, so that any one who has the API URL can't just open a browser and execute the API. For that what are the next steps I must do in my template? I already have API/lambda created with this usage plan.